# XAMPP OSX Snow Leopard & php ssh2 extension

Tags: mac-osx, xampp, php

I've been having problems getting the php ssh2 extension to work under xampp on Snow Leopard in my local test environment. I understand xampp is 32 bit and so the extension must be compiled as 32 bit and have found a couple of tutorials detailing how to do this. However, compiling the ssh2 extension requires the libssh2 library to be present for the compiler to access and I'm unsure how to compile libssh2 in 32 bit and force the extension compiler to in turn find/use it - currently it just reports the libssh2 library required version cannot be found.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did in the end get this working, only to find that the php ssh2 functions are absolutely useless. Instead I'm using [PHP Secure Communications Library](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) which is much much better and allows me to do everything that the php ssh2 functions claimed they could do and more!